# SQL Sentence Prestashop

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I´m trying to get a sql sentence of the table ps_orders, of prestashop, that returns me the following data: "I wanna get the abandoned orders, with a value greater than 20, just for registered users without a more recent order". 
I have tried the following sentence:
`SELECT * , MAX(  "date_add" ) AS  "Date" FROM  "ps_orders" WHERE  "id_customer" >0 AND  "shipping_number" >0 AND  "total_paid" >20 GROUP BY  "id_customer"`

So I have "abandoned orders" using `shipping_number` I also have "registered users" using `id_customer` and higher values than 20 with `total_paid` my problem is on selecting just if they havent got any later bought. Any help will be preciated.

Comment: You mean abondonated carts or orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Prestashop so much, then I only work with your SQL problem. Sorry for the mistakes.

You can do it with a subselect, I think in something like:

```
SELECT pso.*, pso.date_add AS 'Date'
FROM  ps_orders pso
WHERE pso.id_customer > 0 AND pso.shipping_number > 0 AND pso.total_paid > 20 
AND pso.date_add = (SELECT MAX(pso2.date_add) FROM ps_orders pso2 WHERE pso2.id_customer = pso.id_customer)
GROUP BY pso.id_customer
;
```

With this you force the registers with no other `date_add` in the future.

Comment: Thanks man! that solved my question, thanks a lot. If u come to La Rioja ur invited to a wine tour ;)